# Understanding WPF data binding scope

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a custom control embedded within a TabItem of the TabControl.  TabControl is Content of main Usercontrol as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlsLibrary.wpf.Alerts.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl DataContext="{Binding Filter}">
            <TabItem>
                <mc:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding Options}"
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I understand is my custom control will inherit DataContext of TabControl, therefore DataContext of my custom control should be set to the "Options" property of Filter object which is DataContext of TabControl.  However, Visual Studio's output window indicates that it is looking for Options in DataContext of parent UserControl.

Even if I use ElementName property of the Binding class, I still cannot get DataContext of my custom control to change, even though property "Filter" of data item implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

What did I miss?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar problem (but not a Tab control issue, so my apologese if this doesnt work) to this a while ago and what I needed to so was to set the `CustomControl` as the control template of the `TabItem`.

```
    <TabControl DataContext="{Binding Filter}">
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <mc:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding Options}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TabItem.Template>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

which actually has an impact of the logic and visual positioning of the `CustomControl` in the inheritance hierarchy.

Try this an let me know if it works

HTH

Comment: Thanks for response but this will not work for my case as in actual implementation, my custom control is part of a control that is child to TabItem.